# Monotouch mp3 errors

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, mp3

I'm playing an mp3 to provide background music to my iPad game, and I am playing the song using this code:

```
audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer.FromUrl(NSUrl.FromFilename(fileName));

audioPlayer.FinishedPlaying += delegate { audioPlayer.Dispose(); audioPlayer=null; };
if (audioPlayer.PrepareToPlay())
    audioPlayer.Play();
```

It works in fact, but when running I am getting a load of error messages in the console. Am I doing it wrong? Should I worry?

This is a dump of the errors I get:

```
2012-05-04 16:22:17.220 Music[42300:22b03] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn: dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn,  262):
    Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable   Referenced from:
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security  
    Expected in:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security    
2012-05-04 16:22:17.223 Music[42300:22b03] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable   Referenced from:
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security  
    Expected in:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security  
2012-05-04 16:22:17.256 Music[42300:22b03] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable   Referenced from:
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security  
    Expected in:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security  
2012-05-04 16:22:17.258 Music[42300:22b03] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn: dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable Referenced from:
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security  
    Expected in:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security  
2012-05-04 16:22:17.260 Music[42300:22b03] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn: dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable Referenced from:
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security  
    Expected in:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security  
2012-05-04 16:22:17.261 Music[42300:22b03] Error loading  /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable Referenced from:
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security  
    Expected in:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security  
2012-05-04 16:22:17.263 Music[42300:22b03] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn: dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable   Referenced from:
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security  
    Expected in:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security  
2012-05-04 16:22:17.264 Music[42300:22b03] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable Referenced from:
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security  
    Expected in:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
```

Answer (score 1):

These errors seem to be harmless (I have seen them a lot, but not noticed any actual problems).

In any case the errors will be fixed in a future version of MonoTouch.

Comment: IIRC those error are **only** seen when using the simulator, not on devices.